# Magento: Issue installing extension

Tags: magento

I have downloaded a Magento extension. The extension is held in two top level folders `'app'` and `'skin'`. I need to FTP these in to the 'magento' folder on the site, although a `'app'` and `'skin'` folder already exist.

What is the solution here?

Comment: You can directly install your extension through magento connect manager. You have to login to magento connect manager and click on browse button to upload package file and press upload button.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well , You can overriter those files. It would be better to take backup.

After installing extension, dont forget to crear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the extension using Magento connect manager. A detailed description can be found here :

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_connect.htm